# How to save jpg file into a folder in python

Tags: python

This question seems really easy, but I could not figure that out. I want to save a jpg file. I used `plt.savefig(fileName)`. I also create a new folder using `import os` and then `os.mkdir('D:\Users\data')`. Now, I want to put this figure into this created folder. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the full path to `savefig`.

```
folderName = 'D:/Users/data'
os.makedirs(folderName)
plt.savefig(os.path.join(folderName, fileName))
```